# Use QListWidget frontend with QTreeWidget backend PyQt

Tags: qt, pyqt, qlistwidget, qtreewidget, pyqt6

I need to have a widget for displaying files and folders in a grid like scrollable container... So I need the view given by ListWidget, with the filesystem architecture of TreeWidget.
How should I implement this?

I thought about using the FileSysteModel but it works only with local files and my filesystem will be virtual.

Comment: Use QStandardItemModel.

Comment: @musicamante How should I implement the path and directories system with it?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I misunderstood your question. What do you mean by "my filsystem will be virtual"?

Comment: @musicamante the files and directories will be on a different computer and I need to present them by GUI (for example like google drive does)...

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=92biLZST6Vg
This is very helpful and the exact answer. This is just in cpp but the implementation should be 90% the same.